# SwiftUI - Hovering a View outside of a Content View

Tags: swiftui

How can I hover a view outside of its content view ?
For e.g content View Height = 400, Hover View Height = 1000
Hover View will need to overlap the content view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State  var isHovering = false

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            print("tap")
        }) {
            Text("Hover Me")
        }.onHover(perform: { hovering in
            isHovering.toggle()
        }).overlay(VStack {
            if self.isHovering {
                Rectangle()
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: 400, height: 1000)
            } else {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }).frame(width: 400, height: 400)
    }
}

In this case, hover view will match content view height.
```

Comment: Did you try my code ?

Comment: Yes, the thing that I'm trying to achieve is that you have a Main View - "the main window"
and the hovering view could be above - the Main View. Something like a tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

When isHovering is true, the height and width of the Text object will be equal to the Rectangle object.

[image]

```
Button(action: {
                print("tap")
            }) {
                Text("Hover Me")
                    .frame(width: self.isHovering ? 400 : .none, height: self.isHovering ? 1000 : .none)
                
            }.onHover(perform: { hovering in
                isHovering.toggle()
            }).overlay(VStack {
                if self.isHovering {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .frame(width: 400, height: 1000)
                } else {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }).frame(width: 400, height: 400)
```